# xsi:nil="true" in soap request

Tags: php, soap, request, xml-nil

I have `xsi:nil="true"` in my soap request. What does mean? How can I pass value on that?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove it set the value in Soap::Data object to arrayref instead of undef. 
say you have Field1 as your key then the Soap Data object would look like :

```
*bless( {
     '_name' => 'Field1',
     '_signature' => [],
     **'_value' => [
                   undef
                 ],**
     '_prefix' => 'm',
     '_attr' => {
                  'id' => '1219615'
                }
 }, 'SOAP::Data' )*
```

and the resulting xml would be : **< m:Field1 xsi:nil=true  id="1219615" />** now if you change the object to :

```
*bless( {
     '_name' => 'Field1',
     '_signature' => [],
     **'_value' => [],**
     '_prefix' => 'm',
     '_attr' => {
                  'id' => '1219615'
                }
}, 'SOAP::Data' )*
```

You will get the desired output **< m:Field1 id="1219615" />**. 
The solution is in perl.

Answer (score 3):

The nillable attribute indicates that the element that the attribute is on is present but has no value, similar to `NULL` in most programming languages.

If you want to assign a value to the element you can do so, however you'll have to remove the `xsi:nil` attribute first, otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: I cannot remove it because that is part of the soap request. Im trying to import data through API